# Volume file paths Windows 7

Tags: windows, file, filesystems

Working on a project with video files on different external hard drives and the xml they gave me with all the file paths all start with /Volume/name_of_disk/ as they made the xml on a Mac. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to /Volume/ in the PC file system (specifically Windows 7), that I could then tack on /name_of_disk/movie_name and have it find my movie. (more or less the same as going to Computer in Windows Explorer?)

End game I'm using Python and can take care of everything on that end, but it's more a Windows file system question, as I just switched over from Mac.

Cheers!

Comment: The closest I can think of is shown in the output of `mountvol`, which gives a path like `\\?\Volume{...}\ ` - but the `{...}` is a UUID, not a "name of disk".

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm trying to dynamically search for drive paths using the drives names I was given. Right now I'm manually switching /Volume/name_of_disk/ to whatever the drive letter happens to be when I plug the drives in, but if I could replace that with say something like /My Computer/name_of_disk/ that'd save some headaches.